# Similar rest calls behave differently: successful call to one Jira Server, while login error for the other Jira server

Tags: rest, shell, curl, ldap, jira

I am trying to make a rest GET call to two different Jira servers, both of same **version 7.13.2**

The two servers are : **jira2.xyz.com** and **jira3.xyz.com**. I am logged into both of them.

**jira2.xyz.com** and **jira3.xyz.com** both log me in via **LDAP**, when I hit the login button.
The only difference in the login process of the two servers is that **jira2.xyz.com** directly logs in via just **LDAP** while **jira3.xyz.com** requires one extra step via **DUO** enabled push notification/entering passcode.
However, DUO step is not required each time I logout and login back into **jira3.xyz.com**(may be DUO maintains some session).

**Code that PASSES and gives expected output:**

```
result=$(curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" "https://jira2.xyz.com/rest/api/2/issue/ISSUE-29142?fields=status")
    echo "Response from server ..." $result
    echo "Key is : "
    key=($( echo $result | jq .'key' ))
    echo $key
    exit
```

**Code that FAILS :**

```
result=$(curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" "https://jira3.xyz.com/rest/api/2/issue/ISSUE-29089?fields=status")
echo "Response from server ..." $result
echo "Key is : "
key=($( echo $result | jq .'key' ))
echo $key
exit
```

As a result of failure, it produces below error output :

```
{"errorMessages":["You do not have the permission to see the specified issue.","Login Required"],"errors":{}}
```

As we can see from above, there's no difference in the codes apart from the server name.

Not sure why this weird behavior. Please let me know if you think I missed out on any important details.
I am developing this on **Windows 10.**

**EDIT 1 : START**

Running the curl command with -v option for jira3 prodduces below output(I have tried my best (quite hard for me as I am not great at reading network logs) and just edited some values just to make sure that I am not giving out any details I am not supposed to) :

```
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, GET is already inferred.
* STATE: INIT => CONNECT handle 0x800012345; line 1491 (connection #-5000)
* Added connection 0. The cache now contains 1 members
* STATE: CONNECT => WAITRESOLVE handle 0x800012345; line 1532 (connection #0)
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying a1b1:1234:4321:5678::zz0:4b3:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* STATE: WAITRESOLVE => WAITCONNECT handle 0x800012345; line 1611 (connection #0)
* Connected to jira3.xyz.com (a1b1:1234:4321:5678::zz0:4b3) port 443 (#0)
* STATE: WAITCONNECT => SENDPROTOCONNECT handle 0x800012345; line 1667 (connection #0)
* Marked for [keep alive]: HTTP default
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [512 bytes data]
* STATE: SENDPROTOCONNECT => PROTOCONNECT handle 0x800012345; line 1682 (connection #0)
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [87 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
{ [3155 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
{ [333 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
{ [4 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
} [70 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
} [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
} [16 bytes data]
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
{ [16 bytes data]
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=Missouri; L=Kansas CIty; O=xyz Corporation; CN=*.xyz.com
*  start date: Jun  4 16:43:33 2018 GMT
*  expire date: Jun  4 17:13:32 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "jira3.xyz.com" matched cert's "*.xyz.com"
*  issuer: <Some issuer detail, which I just replaced by few random characters>
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* STATE: PROTOCONNECT => DO handle 0x800012345; line 1701 (connection #0)
} [5 bytes data]
> GET /rest/api/2/issue/ISSUE-29089?fields=status HTTP/1.1
> Host: jira3.xyz.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.66.0
> Accept: application/json
>
* STATE: DO => DO_DONE handle 0x800012345; line 1756 (connection #0)
* STATE: DO_DONE => PERFORM handle 0x800012345; line 1877 (connection #0)
{ [5 bytes data]
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
* HTTP 1.1 or later with persistent connection
< HTTP/1.1 401
< X-AREQUESTID: 934x7042171x9
< X-ANODEID: node2
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self'
< X-ASEN: SEN-8803321
* Added cookie atlassian.xsrf.token="ABCD-WXYZ-1234-4PWR_1f2g5s3gs52h7d645gh673h5Fg2F425gsty27856_lout" for domain jira3.xyz.com, path /, expire 0
< Set-Cookie: atlassian.xsrf.token=ABCD-WXYZ-1234-4PWR_1f2g5s3gs52h7d645gh673h5Fg2F425gsty27856_lout; Path=/; Secure
< X-AUSERNAME: anonymous
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, no-transform
< WWW-Authenticate: OAuth realm="https%3A%2F%2Fjira3.xyz.com"
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Date: Mon, 23 Mar 2020 20:34:00 GMT
* Added cookie BIGipServer~Prod~pool_jira3_prd_8080="120400004.12345.8765" for domain jira3.xyz.com, path /, expire 0
< Set-Cookie: BIGipServer~Prod~pool_jira3_prd_8080=120400004.12345.8765; path=/; Httponly; Secure
* no chunk, no close, no size. Assume close to signal end
* Marked for [closure]: HTTP: No end-of-message indicator
<
{ [109 bytes data]
* nread <= 0, server closed connection, bailing
* STATE: PERFORM => DONE handle 0x800012345; line 2067 (connection #0)
* multi_done
100   109    0   109    0     0     56      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--    56
* Closing connection 0
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, close notify (256):
} [2 bytes data]
* The cache now contains 0 members
Response from server ... {"errorMessages":["You do not have the permission to see the specified issue.","Login Required"],"errors":{}}
Key is :
null
```

**EDIT 2 : END**

Comment: How is jira2 able to fetch the details without providing any auth information in curl ?

Comment: @Logu The jira login(and all other tools we use) makes use of the AD, so we don't have to manually enter the credentials to login.

Comment: In my earlier approach I sued to provide login credentials as part of Authorization headers, but later I tried without the credentials and for this to work I had to be logged in to the server beforehand(went to jira2 or jira3 page --> clicked on login --> this triggered automatic login and I was logged in). I wanted to try this approach because theere is just no need of everytime asking the developers for credentials, if the Jira server uses AD.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, it authenticates the user based on the windows system login and the curl is aware of this (ntlm or whatever it is) and able to login. But the jira3 as you mentioned requires 2FA and it might be doing a HTTP/302 redirect.
Once the passcode is given the auth server might send a setcookie with authtoken. Check it with `curl -v` option

Comment: just ran the command with -v option and it prints out detailed output. I will update my OP with the output under section EDIT 1

Comment: @Logu Just updated the OP with full output.Thanks

Comment: curl is not sending any auth related information
`> GET /rest/api/2/issue/ISSUE-29089?fields=status HTTP/1.1
> Host: jira3.xyz.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.66.0
> Accept: application/json`

If the server requires authentication, either there should be some kind of token or authorisation header to be passed to be able to authenticate the client.

Comment: @Logu So if my understanding is correct you are essentially saying that for servers that authenticate via two-factor authentication mechanism ,require some ind of token or authorization header to be passed. I checked the curl -v output for jira2 server and saw that it also returns similar output i.e. without any mention of authorization header "
> GET /rest/api/2/issue/ISSUE-29142?fields=status HTTP/1.1
> Host: jira2.xyz.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.66.0
> Accept: application/json
"

Comment: As my script will run locally on developer system,  I will need to figure out ways to fetch and pass tokens fro that particular developer and this will hopefully solve my issue. Please let me know if my understanding/approach is correct. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jira documentation at https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-cookie-based-authentication/ says :

> **"** Jira's REST API is protected by the same restrictions which are provided via Jira's standard web interface. **"**

So the above statement essentially means that as the **jira2** server in this case is configured to authenticate via **AD**, any rest call to this server would also be authenticated via AD **(** **i.e.** no need to provide credentials explicitly in the request **)** and as **jira3** is configured to use **2FA(AD + DUO)**, so we need to provide an API token for the rest call to succeed.

**As per documentation :**

> If you enable two-step verification on an account that is used by
>   scripts or services to access Atlassian Cloud REST APIs, then that
>   account won't be able to use a password for basic authentication
>   against a REST API. We recommend that you use an API token instead,
>   although an organization admin could exclude the relevant account from
>   two-step verification. Read more about API tokens.

**Related documentation on 2FA**  :https://confluence.atlassian.com/cloud/two-step-verification-976161185.html

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the curl command you mentioned I dont see any username or password.

The curl command should look like this:

```
curl -D- -u USERNAME:PASSWORD  https://jira3.xyz.com/rest/api/2/issue/ISSUE-29089?fields=status
```

Maybe the curl command is succeeding in jira2 because issues are browsable (public) without needing to login:

Try to access the same Jira issue that was successfully retrievable using rest. Try to access using browser with url in a Guest mode session from chrome.

https://jira2.xyz.com/browse/ISSUE-29142

If Jira2 redirected to login page then discard my answer. Currently this is my only diagnosis.

Comment: Thanks for your response. You are right,I 'm able to see the json resp for jira2 without logging in. But that's only because jira servers here are configured to use AD for authentication. The jira documentation https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-cookie-based-authentication/ says :"Jira's REST API is protected by the same restrictions which are provided via Jira's standard web interface." As for the jira3, it uses 2FA and for that an API token is must , here is more on it :https://confluence.atlassian.com/cloud/two-step-verification-976161185.html